# python list item combinations

Tags: python, list

I want to do a comparison between every pair of elements in the list without the following:
DIFFERENCE=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

1. no self comparisons
2. no reverse comparisons

So the answer will be [1,2],[1,3],[1,4],[1,5],[1,6],[2,3],[4,5],[5,6],[3,4],[2,4],[2,5],[3,6],[2,6],[3,5],[4,6]
I have written this so far but I was looking for a faster way.

```
for i in DIFFERENCE:
       for j in DIFFERENCE:
           if(some condition and i!=j and i+'_'+j not in COMPARISON and j+'_'+i not in COMPARISON):
               COMPARISON.append(i+'_'+j);
               COMPARISON.append(j+'_'+i);
               ANS_COUNT=ANS_COUNT+1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just use `itertools.combinations`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```

Comment: Hi I was wondering if you can give me some insights into why I am getting the following error when I run : TMP_DIFF=[list(i) for i in list(itertools.combinations(DIFFERENCE2, 2))]; MemoryError. Atfirst, I thought may be len(DIFFERENCE2) =0,1,2 was a problem so I wrote,if(len(DIFFERENCE2)>2):TMP_DIFF=[list(i) for i in list(itertools.combinations(DIFFERENCE2, 2))];but the error this persists. Please comment.

Comment: @mparida: How big is `DIFFERENCE2`? If it's more than a few tens of thousands of entries long, you'll run out of memory constructing every possible combination. In that case, consider iterating over the `itertools.combinations` output directly, which will "lazily" generate the combinations for you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply nneonneo I am not sure how big is DIFFERENCE2 but like you said I am assuming it is pretty big to flag such an error. I am not sure if I understand the last line In that case, consider iterating over the itertools.combinations output directly, which will "lazily" generate the combinations for you..please explain. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using for loop:

```
l = list()
for i in range (1,7):
    for j in range (2,7):
        if(i == j):
            j = j + 1
        elif ((i,j) in l or (j,i) in l):
            continue
        else:
            l.append((i,j))

print l
```

output:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 6)]
```